# Flexslider not showing on IndexPage

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am really new to ASP.net. So pardon me if my question seems stupid. Seems like I have tried everything for the Flexslider to show on my index page, but I can't seem to make it work.
Here's the code for my _Layout page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>

    <!-- mobile settings -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, initial scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <!-- WEB FONTS : use %7C instead of | (pipe) -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400%7CRaleway:300,400,500,600,700%7CLato:300,400,400italic,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- CORE CSS -->
    <link href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- THEME CSS -->
    <link href="~/assets/css/essentials.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <link href="~/assets/css/header-1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/assets/css/color_scheme/green.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="color_scheme" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody();

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> var plugin_path = '~/assets/plugins/'</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

    <!-- STYLESWITCHER - REMOVE -->
    @*<script async type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/styleswitcher/styleswitcher.js"></script>*@

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Now Here's the code for my Index Page where I have flexslider defined.

```html
<body>
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <!-- Slide 1 -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="~/assets/images/demo/content_slider/10-min.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
                            <div class="flex-caption">My text 1</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Slide 2 -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="~/assets/images/demo/content_slider/3-min.jpg" alt="Slide 3">
                            <div class="flex-caption">My text 2</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Slide 3 -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="~/assets/images/demo/content_slider/21-min.jpg" alt="Slide 4">
                            <div class="flex-caption">My text 3</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Slide 4 -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="~/assets/images/demo/content_slider/23-min.jpg" alt="Slide 5">
                            <div class="flex-caption"My text 4</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</body>
```

Can somebody please help me with this. I am using a smarty bootstrap template. All the path to css class are valid and all the js scripts are valid.

I have tried endless options to make this work but i had no luck so far.

Comment: What specifically is the problem?  Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Sorry for the bad question. I figured it out. There was ~ in the below line
var plugin_path = '~/assets/plugins/';</script>
because of that reason the script were not loading dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I had tilda (~) in this line 
 var plugin_path = '~/assets/plugins/'

Because of the ~ the js scripts were not loading. I removed the ~ and the flexslider is showing up now.